# sharepoint notifications

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert

Is it possible to bring my custom property values to the Newsfeed? For example consider I have FAQ's or something similar to it. If I ask a question, and if that question is answered I want that in the Newsfeed; is it possible? To be specific I want that entire custom list to be viewed in the Newsfeed.